# Azure AD - Assign Users and Groups to App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure AD:

- I've added users via Microsoft Account IDs.
- I have activated "Azure AD Premium" trial
- I've assigned each user a license

Now I want to assign users access to my Web App (A cloud service), however, I'm not seeing the "Users and Groups" tab described in this article:

> Important:
>   You will only see the Users and Groups tab once you have enabled Azure AD Premium.
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/active-directory-accessmanagement-group-saasapps/

And even demonstrated in this video:
http://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/videos/configure-and-assign-groups-azure-ad/

Finally, when I go to:
https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/default.aspx
I'm not seeing any "Apps" - I assume once I've been able to assign access the Apps should show here.

EDIT:

I've found some info which looks like it is not possible to sign in to Cloud Service Web App with Azure AD using a Microsoft Account:

> The Azure AD scenarios and solutions (and our code samples and sample applications) require a user account in the domain of your Azure Active Directory. If you try to sign in to the applications with a Microsoft account, such as a Hotmail.com, Live.com, or Outlook.com account, the sign in fails.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151790.aspx

Code Sample:

> This sample will not work with a Microsoft account, so if you signed in to the Azure portal with a Microsoft account and have never created a user account in your directory before, you need to do that now.
>   https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

**Is it possible to sign in using a Microsoft Account / is there a worked sample/guide?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning users and groups to applications feature is available for pre-integrated Azure AD SaaS applications. Once a user is assigned to an app, the app's icon appears in the users access panel. In some cases assigning a user provisions an account for the user in the SaaS app.

This AzureAD capability isn't yet available for other applications (e.g. apps developed in-house).

Note that a user doesn't need to be assigned to an application to be able to sign-in to it. Once an in-house developed application gets registered in the directory, users in that directory can sign-in to the application. So you shouldn't block on this.

KiereH, we are considering extending assign users and groups to non-pre-integrated applications too - and give the ability to assign them to an application role at assignment. Please stay tuned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.
The users whom I have added though aren't able to sign in, they get "We don't recognize the username or password" at the MS Sign in page.

Comment: To clarify, users from the Azure AD directory I provisioned can sign-in.
But users cannot sign-in via Microsoft Account (refer to my edit).

Comment: @KierenH, you can't currently use a Microsoft Account to sign in to applications, like you've discovered in the documentation.

Comment: You can sign in to application with a microsoft account just fine if you somehow manage to get the live login page.. for example by typing bla@live.com it will take you to the live login where you can use a microsoft account to login - if only there was a a way to force the live login page to come up instead of the AD signin

Comment: Is this still accurate?

Comment: What if your using RBAC? How can I assign a role to a group and then a group to an application?