# Azure AD ACS filter users by group

Tags: azure, active-directory, acs

I have an MVC application and i use Azure AD (premium) ACS authentication to allow users access.
The thing is that i want to allow only specific users to sign-in and not for all the AD members.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763602/azure-ad-assign-users-and-groups-to-app) post that a side comment it said that regardless to who is assigned and who is not - any way all users can sign in. Also i found that the ACS cannot receive the user groups detailed (without using graph api). So is there a way to allow access only for users from a specific group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you talk about Access Control Service - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/.

ACS can recieve all the user goups. And this is done in the Rule Groups. You can transform AAD Group claim into Role Claim. Thus having your AAD groups turn in ASP.NET roles. Then you can simply create a new group in AAD, enlist only set of users in this group. Later you can configure your authorization rules in MVC to require that specific Role. There are two interesting reading on ACS subject:

- [ACS as federation provider, claims transformation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2011/02/14/acs-as-a-federation-provider-claims-transformation.aspx)
- [Federated Identity with Microsoft ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446535.aspx)

Comment: "You can transform AAD Group claim into Role Claim", how?? I'v tried convert "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups" ==> "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role". Is this what you mean? cus i can't make it work.. Thanks for yor help!